# Can't update Xubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa (LTS) to the next LTS release (22.04 Jammy)

Tags: upgrade, updates, xubuntu

The do-release-upgrade(8) program says I need to install all updates before it can go to work

I have done what I can (all as root):

```
    apt-get --quiet --assume-yes update
    apt-get --quiet --assume-yes upgrade
```

At which point it says these packages have been kept back:
fwupd-signed gnome-software gnome-software-common gnome-software-plugin-snap ubuntu-software

This system was Ubuntu when delivered  (by System76), and I changed it to Xubuntu.  Could these be remnants of Ubuntu?

In any case, what can I do now?

Comment: I suggest you read your messages; you must apply all security fixes before you can *release-upgrade*, and you haven't actually indicated that you have. Have you applied any *holds* to prevent upgrade? as these also prevent *release-upgrade*.. (`apt-mark showhold`).  Some upgrades (esp. sources) require `apt full-upgrade` which you don't mention attempting... etc... but you'll have the best clues if you read your messages.. and update `wupd-signed gnome-software gnome-software-common gnome-software-plugin-snap ubuntu-software` which include *snap* packages (`snap refresh` whilst not being used)

Comment: When I did the upgrade, lots of individual updates said they were about security.  I don't understand the reference to apt-mark but will look it up.  I also never encountered full-upgrade before, so thanks for that. Likewise wupd-signed and snap refresh.  Just a note: I dislike snaps and have never before intentionally touched them.  And by "read your messages" do you mean the output from the commands I have mentioned, or something else?

Comment: Check for the packages if they are in phased state with `apt-cache policy packagename`

Comment: Okay, so... `snap refresh` said everything was up to date. `apt-mark showhold` showed nothing.  `apt full-upgrade` upgraded nothing and showed the same 3 things held back.  `wupd-signed` was not found.

Comment: `apt-cache` showed the installed and candidate versions for each package, plus a version table.  No mention of holds.

Comment: Not hold but shown as phased ?

Comment: I did not see "phase" in any output whatever.  I don't even know what it means, come to that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very tentative alternative I'm considering (reluctantly -- it is a lot of work):

- Install a fresh Focal in an empty partition (yes I have a few).
- Do a `dpkg --get-selections` on the old system, and `dpkg --set-selections` on the new one.  Make sure the packages mentioned as held back are not included, because I'm not aware of any need for them and if they didn't get installed with the fresh install, I don't want them. Then `apt-get dselect-upgrade`.
- Check for third-party packages (not sure if I have any on this system, but perhaps I do)
- Copy `/root` and my home directory and all the `/local/` and `/.local/` directories, plus do a `vimdiff` on all the config files.
- Try an update